# Is there an easy way to find a .css source file from a website inspection window?

Tags: css, themes, magento2

I'm trying to customize a theme for a Magento 2 website (it was purchased), and for the most part I know where most of the .css calls are coming from. However, there is one sub-menu, I cannot find the source css file for the life of me.

Normally I use Chrome's inspection window to identify the css that is generating the colors/details that I'm looking for, and then search the source files for the same .css reference, and then make the modification as needed.

However, as mentioned I'm struggling to find a specific piece of css code, and I'm wondering if there might be a better way to find what I'm looking for?

Comment: http://bricss.net/post/33788072565/using-sass-source-maps-in-webkit-inspector - try this one)

Comment: @ФредГенкин Post your answer as an actual answer (so you can get points for it). Following your post absolutely made this happen! Woot, whoduthunk grunt was my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://bricss.net/post/33788072565/using-sass-source-maps-in-webkit-inspector - Try this one!

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/source-maps?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3 - this is how you set up your css source mapping by using default developer tools :)

Comment: For anybody else reading this:
you'll also need: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html

and one small trick: Make sure you have your admin > configuration > advanced > developer > Frontend Development Workflow > Workflow Type: = Server Side LESS Compilation, otherwise Client side will over-ride and you won't see anything.